# OS X Finder "New Folder" is dimmed out

Tags: macos, finder

I'm having an issue with my macbook pro running OS X 10.6: when I go to create a new folder from the finder the "New Folder" option is completely disabled.

The finder help points to a permissions problem, but when I click on the parent folder and hit permissions I see that I'm the owner (the info box even helpfully says "(me)"), and that I have read and write access.

As a workaround I'm creating folders from the command line using mkdir (with the same account), but I'd like to be able to do this graphically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see this icon in the corner of the window?

[image: nowrite]

If so, that does indicate that you can't write to the folder.

You might try running Repair Permissions in Disk Utility (click on the disk, then First Aid > Verify/Repair Disk Permissions).

Comment: That icon is indeed there. I ran repair permissions and it appeared to do a bunch of stuff, but unfortunately the icon remained. I'm going to run "verify permissions" now and see what happens. thanks!

Comment: When you check the permissions via Get Info, try looking at the folder you're trying to create a folder in, not the one above it (unless that's what you were doing...)

Comment: I spoke too soon, I ran verify and then fix and it worked! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this folder on some form of external device?  Sometimes you may plug in some device, such as a flash disk or memory card or external hard drive that has one of two circmstances:

1) The device itself is write
    protected, which means that though
    you have the "permission" based on
    Mac permissions, the device itself
    has been mounted as Read-Only.

2) The device is of a filesystem type
    not supported for Read-Write by OS
    X.  Again, you can see it, but you
    won't be able to perform write
    operations, such as creating a new
    folder.

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn't clear - this is my macbook pro's primary hard drive.

Comment: I am using an external HDD that I usually use on Linux so that explains why I'm unable to write to the drive. Do you have any resources as to how I can make it writeable?

Answer (score 0):

If you can write to the folder in Terminal as yourself without sudo but not in Finder it sounds like Finder is crashed.

If you run **ls -lR $problemfolder** what do you see?

Comment: I assume you mean the permissions - they are:

drwxr-xr-x 

and I am the owner of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a tags folder, it won't let you create a folder; but if you go to your Documents and from there access the tag folder you were initially working one, there you can create a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.  I'm not sure if you had the same problem, but I was trying to create a new folder from recents, which is impossible.  Click on downloads or some other area to create a folder to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I was logged in as my usual user.  I selected `Get Info`.  My user had `Read & Write` access, however directly below `Sharing & Permissions` it displayed `You can read only`.

- I logged out (I selected to NOT reopen programs)
- Logged in

Once I was logged in I was able to create a `New Folder`.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I guess - maybe wrong - the new system allows us to create new folder ONLY after the first layer which has been customized as only 4 folders. You can go one layer down and see the function of creating new folder under which you can create new folder at will. I put all my documents under the user folder.